# Why does a function with no parameters (compared to the actual function definition) compile?

Tags: c, parameters, void, function-prototypes, function-parameter

I've just come across someone's C code that I'm confused as to why it is compiling. There are two points I don't understand.

1. The **function prototype** has no parameters compared to the actual function definition.
2. The parameter in the **function definition** does not have a type.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func();

int func(param)
{
    return param;
}

int main()
{
    int bla = func(10);    
    printf("%d", bla);
}
```

Why does this work?
I have tested it in a couple of compilers, and it works fine.

Comment: It's K&R C. We wrote code like this in the 1980s before there were full function prototypes.

Comment: surprised there were no warnings..

Comment: gcc does warn with `-Wstrict-prototypes` for both the `int func()` and `int main()`: x.c:3: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype. You should declare `main()` as `main(void)` as well.

Comment: Kinda sleepy. But "function definition doesn't have a type". Where?

Comment: @Jens Why did you edit the question? You seem to have missed the point...

Comment: I just made the implicit int explicit. How does that miss the point? I believe the point is why `int func();` is compatible with `int func(arglist) { ... }`.

Comment: @Jens Part of the reason this code was so confusing (to me) was the implicit `int`. Also note the part of the question that says "Secondly, the parameter in the function definition doesn't have a type."

Comment: BTW, someone edited the question to become bogus: it says prototype when the point is that it is **NOT A PROTOTYPE**.

Comment: Technically, main(void) is not valid. It works in most compilers, but it's incorrect. it is either `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or `int main()` if you don't care about argc and argv.

Comment: @MatsPetersson This is wrong. C99 5.1.2.2.1 expressly contradicts your claim and states that the no argument version is `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Jens if you have a better title, edit the title. C is not my first, second, or even third language. It's a book on my shelf, sadly.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

All the other answers are correct, but just for [completion](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.3.html)

> A function is declared in the following manner:
>
> ```
>   return-type function-name(parameter-list,...) { body... }
> ```
>
> **return-type** is the variable type that the function returns. This can not be an array type or a function type. **If not given, then int
>   is assumed**.
>
> **function-name** is the name of the function.
>
> **parameter-list** is the list of parameters that the function takes separated by commas. ***If no parameters are given, then the function
>   does not take any and should be defined with an empty set of
>   parenthesis or with the keyword void. If no variable type is in front
>   of a variable in the paramater list, then int is assumed***. Arrays and
>   functions are not passed to functions, but are automatically converted
>   to pointers. If the list is terminated with an ellipsis (,...), then
>   there is no set number of parameters. Note: the header stdarg.h can be
>   used to access arguments when using an ellipsis.

And again for the sake of completeness. [From C11 specification 6:11:6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (page: 179)

> The **use of function declarators with empty parentheses** (not
>   prototype-format parameter type declarators) **is an obsolescent
>   feature**.

Comment: ***"If no variable type is in front of a variable in the parameter list, then int is assumed."*** I see this in yours provided link, but I can not find it in any standard c89, c99... Can you provide another source?

Comment: "If no parameters are given, then the function does not take any and should be defined with an empty set of parenthesis" sounds contradictory to [Tony The Lion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950669/2828064) but I just learned that Tony The Lion's answer is correct the hard way.

Answer (score 161):

In C `func()` means that you can pass any number of arguments.  If you want no arguments then you have to declare as `func(void)`. The type you're passing to your function, if not specified defaults to `int`.

Comment: Actually there's no single type defaulting to int. In fact, all args default to int (even the return type). It is perfectly ok to call `func(42,0x42);` (where *all* calls must use the two args form).

Comment: In C it is quite common for unspecified types to default to *int* like for example when you declare a variable: unsigned x; What type is the variable x? It turns out its *unsigned int*

Comment: I'd rather say implicit int **was** common in the olden days. It certainly isn't any longer and in C99 it was removed from C.

Comment: It may be worthwhile noting that this answer applies to function prototypes with empty parameter lists, but *not* function definitions with empty parameter lists.

Comment: @mnemonicflow that's not an "unspecified type defaulting to int"; `unsigned` is just another name for the same type as `unsigned int`.

Comment: @hobbs Sure, but it's the same old reasoning used for function parameters, if no type is specified int is assumed. Just saying "unsigned" doesn't tell me anything about what is the actual type (e.g. is it unsigned short or unsigned int64?, etc.)

Comment: you can also declare a variable like `static x;`, `const x;` or `auto x;` and it'll default to `int`

Answer (score 61):

`int func();` is an obsolescent function declaration from the days when there was no C standard, i.e. the days of **K&R C** (before 1989, the year the first "ANSI C" standard was published).

Remember that there were *no prototypes in K&R C* and the keyword `void` was not yet invented. All you could do was to tell the compiler about the *return type* of a function. The empty parameter list in K&R C means "an unspecified but fixed" number of arguments. Fixed means that you must call the function with the *same* number of args each time (as opposed to a *variadic* function like `printf`, where the number and type can vary for each call).

Many compilers will diagnose this construct; in particular `gcc -Wstrict-prototypes` will tell you "function declaration isn't a prototype", which is spot on, because it *looks* like a prototype (especially if you are poisoned by C++!), but isn't. It's an old style K&R C return type declaration.

**Rule of thumb:** Never leave an empty parameter list declaration empty, use `int func(void)` to be specific.
This turns the K&R return type declaration into a proper C89 prototype. Compilers are happy, developers are happy, static checkers are happy. Those mislead by^W^Wfond of C++ may cringe, though, because they need to type extra characters when they try to exercise their foreign language skills :-)

Comment: Please don't relate this to C++. It is *common sense* that empty argument list means *no parameters*, and people of the world are not interested to deal with mistakes made by K&R guys some 40 years ago. But committee pundits keep dragging contranatural choices along - into C99, C11.

Comment: @pfalcon *Common sense* is quite subjective. What's common sense to one person is plain insanity to others. Professional C programmers know that empty parameter lists indicate an unspecified but fixed number of arguments. Changing that would likely break many implementations. Blaming committees for avoiding silent changes is barking up the wrong tree, IMHO.

Answer (score 53):

- The empty parameter list means "any arguments", so the definition isn't wrong.
- The missing type is assumed to be `int`.

I would consider any build that passes this to be lacking in configured warning/error level though, there's no point in being this allowing for actual code.

Answer (score 30):

It's **K&R** style function declaration and definition. From C99 Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:TC3)

Section 6.7.5.3 Function Declarators (including prototypes)

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty
>   list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
>   function has no parameters. **The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the
>   parameters is supplied. (If both function types are "old style", parameter types are not compared.)**

Section 6.11.6 Function declarators

> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
>   type declarators) is an **obsolescent feature.**

Section 6.11.7 Function definitions

> The use of function definitions with separate parameter identifier and declaration lists
>   (not prototype-format parameter type and identifier declarators) is an **obsolescent feature.**

Which the old style means **K&R** style

Example:

Declaration: `int old_style();`

Definition:

```
int old_style(a, b)
    int a; 
    int b;
{
     /* something to do */
}
```

Answer (score 16):

**C assumes `int` if no type is given on function return type and parameter list**. Only for this rule following weird things are possible.

A function definition looks like this.

```
int func(int param) { /* body */}
```

If its a prototype you write

```
int func(int param);
```

In prototype you can only specify the type of parameters. Parameters' name is not mandatory. So

```
int func(int);
```

Also if you dont specify parameter type but name `int` is assumed as type.

```
int func(param);
```

If you go farther, following works too.

```
func();
```

Compiler assumes `int func()` when you write `func()`. But dont put `func()` inside a function body. That'll be a function call

Comment: An empty parameter list is not related to the implicit int type. `int func()` is not an implicit form of `int func(int)`.

Answer (score 11):

As stated @Krishnabhadra, all previous responses from other users, have a correct interpretation, and I just want to make a more detailed analysis of some points.

In the Old-C as in ANSI-C the "**untyped formal parameter**", take the dimencion of your work register or instruction depth  capability  (shadow registers or instruction cumulative cycle), in an 8bit MPU, will be an int16, in a 16bit MPU and so will be an int16 an so on, in the case 64bit architectures may choose to compile options like: -m32.

*Although it seems simpler implementation at high level,
For pass multiple parameters, the work of the programmer in the control dimencion  data type step, becomes more demanding.*

In other cases, for some  microprocessors architectures, the ANSI compilers customized, leveraged some of this old features to optimize the use of the code, forcing the location of these "untyped formal parameters" to work within or outside the work register, today you get almost the same with the use of "volatile" and "register".

**But it should be noted that the most modern compilers,
not make any distinction between the two types of parameters declaration.**

Examples of a compilation with gcc under linux:

[image: main.c]

[image: main2.c]

[image: main3.c]
 

*In any case the statement of the prototype locally is of no use, because there is no call without parameters reference to this prototype will be remiss.
If you use the system with "untyped formal parameter", for an external call, proceed to generate a declarative prototype data type.*

Like this:

```
int myfunc(int param);
```

Comment: I have taken the trouble to optimize images for that the size in bytes of the images, was the minimum possible. I think the pictures can get a quick view of the lack of difference in the generated code.
I've been testing out the code, generating real documentation of what it claimed and not just theorizing about the problem. but not all see the world the same way.
I'm terribly sorry that my attempt to provide more information to the community to have bothered you so much.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that an unspecified return type is always `int`, which is generally either the work-register size or 16 bits, whichever is smaller.

Comment: @supercat +1 Perfect deduction, you are right! This is exactly what I discuss above, a compiler designed  by default for a specifies architecture , always reflect the size of the work-register of the CPU / MPU in question, 
So in an embedded enviroment, there are various re-typing strategy on a realtime OS, into a compiler layer (stdint.h),  or into a portability layer, that makes portable the same OS in many others arquitectures, and obtained by alignment the CPU / MPU specific types (int, long, long long, etc) with the generic system types u8, u16, u32.

Comment: @supercat Without control types offered by an operating system or by specific compiler, you need have a bit attencion in development time, and,  you make that all "untyped assignments" are align with your application design,  before have the surprise of finding a "16bit int" and not a "32bit int".

Comment: @RTOSkit: Your answer suggests that the default type on an 8-bit processor will be an Int8.  I do recall a couple C-ish compilers for the PICmicro brand architecture where that was the case, but I don't think anything remotely resembling a C standard has ever allowed an `int` type which was not capable both of holding all values in the range -32767 to +32767 (note -32768 is not required) and also capable of holding all `char` values (meaning that if `char` is 16 bits, either it must be signed or `int` must be bigger).

Comment: @supercat ahh! ok now I understand your comment, excellent observation! it is true all standard compilers guarantee for an int 16bits and there customizations where you might find a int8 as datatype,
also in 8bits data micros with 14,16,18bits instructions is guaranteed a 16-bit integer.  I modified the answer thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding parameter type, there are already correct answers here but if you want to hear it from the compiler you can try adding some flags (flags are almost always a good idea anyways).

compiling your program using `gcc foo.c -Wextra` I get:

```
foo.c: In function ‘func’:
foo.c:5:5: warning: type of ‘param’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wmissing-parameter-type]
```

strangely `-Wextra` doesn't catch this for `clang` (it doesn't recognize `-Wmissing-parameter-type` for some reason, maybe for historical ones mentioned above) but `-pedantic` does:

```
foo.c:5:10: warning: parameter 'param' was not declared, 
defaulting to type 'int' [-pedantic]
int func(param)
         ^
1 warning generated.
```

And for prototype issue as said again above `int func()` refers to arbitrary parameters unless you exclicitly define it as `int func(void)` which would then give you the errors as expected:

```
foo.c: In function ‘func’:
foo.c:6:1: error: number of arguments doesn’t match prototype
foo.c:3:5: error: prototype declaration
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:12:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘func’
foo.c:5:5: note: declared here
```

or in `clang` as:

```
foo.c:5:5: error: conflicting types for 'func'
int func(param)
    ^
foo.c:3:5: note: previous declaration is here
int func(void);
    ^
foo.c:12:20: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
    int bla = func(10);
              ~~~~ ^~
foo.c:3:1: note: 'func' declared here
int func(void);
^
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 3):

If the function declaration has no parameters i.e. empty then it is taking unspecified number of arguments. If you want to make it take no arguments then change it to:

```
int func(void);
```

Comment: _"If the function prototype has no parameters"_ That's not a function prototype, just a function declaration.

Comment: @effeffe fixed that. I didn't realize this question would get a lot of attention ;)

Comment: Isn't "function prototype" just an alternate (possibly old-fashioned) expression for "function declaration"?

Comment: @Giorgio IMO, both are correct. "function prototype" should match "function definition". I probably think effeffe meant declaration in the question and what I meant is in my answer.

Comment: @Giorgio no, function declaration are made by the return type value, the identifier and an _optional_ parameter list; function prototypes are function declaration with a parameter list.

Comment: @KingsIndian function prototypes and function definitions are unrelated, a definition is made by a declaration and a body for the function, but there could be a prototype without a definition and a definition without a prototype. But we're talking about poor practice.

Comment: @effeffe For example, `void func(int);` can considered as both declaration in the old forms that's what giorgio says, which is mentioned in the quoted standard.

Comment: @KingsIndian If you're talking about old K&R C, I just don't know how things are named there. :)

Comment: @effeffe Function prototypes were not there in K&R C. The "protypes" you say were added only after C89.

Comment: @KingsIndian Yes I knew that, I just don't know if people used to call things differently before standardization process. However, I think it doesn't make much sense to talk about these details without a standardization. Thanks however for pointing out that things used to be different.

Answer (score 0):

This is why I typically advise people to compile their code with:

```
cc -Wmissing-variable-declarations -Wstrict-variable-declarations -Wold-style-definition
```

These flags enforce a couple of things:

- -Wmissing-variable-declarations: It is impossible to declare a non-static function without getting a prototype first. This makes it more likely that a prototype in a header file matches with the actual definition. Alternatively, it enforces that you add the static keyword to functions that don't need to be visible publicly.
- -Wstrict-variable-declarations: The prototype must properly list the arguments.
- -Wold-style-definition: The function definition itself must also properly list the arguments.

These flags are also used by default in a lot of Open Source projects. For example, FreeBSD has these flags enabled when building with WARNS=6 in your Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

> **In the old-style declarator**,

> the identifier list must be absent unless
> the declarator is used in the head of a function definition
> (Par.A.10.1). No information about the types of the parameters is
> supplied by the declaration. For example, the declaration

```
int f(), *fpi(), (*pfi)();
```

> declares a function f returning an integer, a function fpi returning a pointer to an integer, >and a pointer pfi to a function returning an integer. In none of these are the parameter types >specified; they are old-style.

> **In the new-style declaration**

`int strcpy(char *dest, const char *source), rand(void);`

> strcpy is a
> function returning int, with two arguments, the first a character
> pointer, and the second a pointer to constant characters

SOURCE:- K&R book

I hope it cleared your doubt..