# Pointer Problems While Checking Directory

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I am making a function (part of a larger project), that checks to see if a file exists in C.  This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
int file_exist(file_path, file_name)
{
  DIR *dp;
  FILE *fc;
  struct dirent *ep;

 dp = opendir(file_path);
 fc = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if(dp = NULL)
    error_escape("Opening path");
  else
    chdir(file_path);
  if(fc = NULL)
  {
    error_escape("Opening file");
    return(-1);
  }
  else
    return(0);
}
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get this result:

```
file_exist.c: In function ‘file_exist’:
file_exist.c:10:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘opendir’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  dp = opendir(file_path);
               ^
In file included from file_exist.c:3:0:
/usr/include/dirent.h:134:13: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern DIR *opendir (const char *__name) __nonnull ((1));
             ^
file_exist.c:11:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  fc = fopen(file_name, "r");
             ^
In file included from file_exist.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:272:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
              ^
```

I have looked in numerous places for a solution, and experimented with many different things to see if I could fix it, but I just don't know what to do.  Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: You haven't declared parameter types, so it's defaulting to int. Try making both of them take `const char*`.

Comment: It would be super if you could include a type specifier for those parameters.. :)

Comment: I think [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18202232/2564301) comes closest as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_exist.c: In function ‘file_exist’:
file_exist.c:10:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘opendir’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  dp = opendir(file_path);
               ^
```

This error is caused because your function is declared as

```
int file_exist(file_path, file_name)
```

Since the parameters' types are not declared, they're assumed to be `int`. You hace to replace this line with

```
int file_exist(char *file_path, char *file_name)
```

However, as David van rijn indicates, there's the issue where you're doing

```
if(dp = NULL)
```

and replacing the value of `dp` with `NULL` instead of checking it. You need to write

```
if(dp == NULL)
```

Additionally, there's a logical error in your code (after these fixes):

```
int file_exist(char *file_path, char *file_name)
{
  DIR *dp;
  FILE *fc;
  struct dirent *ep;

  dp = opendir(file_path);
  fc = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if(dp == NULL)
    error_escape("Opening path");
  else
    chdir(file_path);
  if(fc == NULL)
  {
    error_escape("Opening file");
    return(-1);
  }
  else
    return(0);
}
```

Because you're opening the file before going to the correct directory. You need to perform the `chdir` before the `fopen`:

```
int file_exist(char *file_path, char *file_name)
{
  DIR *dp;
  FILE *fc;
  struct dirent *ep;

  dp = opendir(file_path);
  if(dp == NULL)
    error_escape("Opening path");
  else
    chdir(file_path);

  fc = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if(fc == NULL)
  {
    error_escape("Opening file");
    return(-1);
  }
  else
    return(0);
}
```

Finally, your code is leaking file descriptors because you're not closing the directory and file you're opening. You need to do something like

```
int file_exist(char *file_path, char *file_name)
{
  DIR *dp;
  FILE *fc;
  struct dirent *ep;

  dp = opendir(file_path);
  if(dp == NULL)
    error_escape("Opening path");
  else
    chdir(file_path);
  closedir(dp);

  fc = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if(fc == NULL)
  {
    error_escape("Opening file");
    return(-1);
  }
  else {
    close(fc);
    return(0);
  }
}
```

A slightly better way to do this is:

```
int file_exist(char *file_path, char *file_name)
{
  int dir;
  FILE *fc;

  dir = chdir(file_path);
  if (dir == -1) {
    error_escape("Opening path");
    return -1;
  }

  fc = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if(fc == NULL)
  {
    error_escape("Opening file");
    return(-1);
  }
  else {
    close(fc);
    return(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is the difference between `=` and `==`. ie. one is assignment, and the other is comparision. 
so turn this

```
if(dp = NULL)
```

into

```
if(dp == NULL)
```

or

```
if(!dp)
```

because now you are assigning `NULL` to dp. T

This has nothing to do with the warnings, but i'd fix them too if i were you.