# "value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" in my easy program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, vector

please can you help me with my easy program? I am begginer and my english is not good, it hard to understand. :/

PROGRAM:

```
void tisk_pole (P);

int main()
{
    char P1[3][3]={{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};
    tisk_pole(P1);
    return 0;
}

void tisk_pole (P){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%c", P[i][j]);  //HERE IS PROBLEM -> value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

PLEASE, can you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: do `void tisk_pole (char P[3][3]){` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the type declaration of the argument `P`.

```
void tisk_pole(char P[3][3]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%c", P[i][j]); 
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

See [C Function with parameter without type indicator still works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202232/c-function-with-parameter-without-type-indicator-still-works) for how compilers treat a parameter with no type.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the `P` parameter in the `tisk_pole` function definition must match the type of the argument `P1` in the function call.

`P1` has type `char [3][3]` - that is, a 3-element array of 3-element array of `char`.  Thus, the declaration of the `P` parameter in `tisk_pole` must be one of the following:

```
void tisk_pole( char P[3][3] )
```

or

```
void tisk_pole( char P[][3] )
```

or

```
void tisk_pole( char (*P)[3] )
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the function call

```
tisk_pole( P1 );
```

the *expression* `P1` has type "3-element array of 3-element array of `char`" (`char [3][3]`); since it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to 3-element array of `char`" (`char (*)[3]`) and evaluates to the address of the first element of `P1`.  This means that `tisk_pole` receives a *pointer* value, not an array value.

In a *function parameter declaration*, `T a[N]`, `T a[]`, and `T *a` all mean the same thing - they all declare `a` as a *pointer* to `T`, not an array of `T`.   This is *only* true in a function parameter declaration, though.

You can use the `[]` subscript operator on pointers the same way you do on arrays, so `P[i][j]` works exactly as you expect it to.