# C - Adding Distance from User Input using struct

Tags: c, struct

I am very new to C and am struggling with this code. I need to get the feet and inches of two athletes from user input using a structure, then total the inches of each athlete to determine the winner. The issue I'm having is that the value being returned doesn't make any sense. My guess is it has something to do with getting the address of the value instead of the actual value, but after changing some things around I just end up with errors or the program crashing. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Distance Structure
struct Distance
{
    int feet;
    float inches;
};

int main() {

    //Initialize athelete structures
    struct Distance athlete1;
    struct Distance athlete2;

    //Get values for athlete 1
    printf("Enter the distance for athlete 1\n");
    printf("Feet: ");
    scanf("%d", &athlete1.feet);
    printf("Inches: ");
    scanf("%d", &athlete1.inches);

    //Get values for athlete 2
    printf("Enter the distance for athlete 2\n");
    printf("Feet: ");
    scanf("%d", &athlete2.feet);
    printf("Inches: ");
    scanf("%d", &athlete2.inches);

    //Convert values to inches
    float total1 = calculateInches(athlete1.feet, athlete1.inches);
    float total2 = calculateInches(athlete2.feet, athlete2.inches);

    //Print distance in inches
    printf("\nAthlete 1 has a distance of %d inches\n", total1);
    printf("Athlete 2 has a distance of %d inches\n\n", total2);

    //Print the winner
    if(total1 > total2){
        printf("Athlete 1 wins!");
    }
    else if(total1 < total2){
        printf("Athlete 2 wins!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Tie!");
    }
    return 0;
}

//Calculate Inches
int calculateInches(feet, inches){
    float total;
    total = (feet*12) + inches;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: While you can declare your `struct Distance` instances one at a time, to handle multiple struct, you generally want to either declare an array of them (if you know a max you will need) or dynamically allocate storage for some number of them (which you can `realloc()` if you need more). Then you can simply loop filling the elements and avoid duplicating all of your user input prompts and reads, etc.. Example `struct Distance athletes[10];` then `int n;` and `for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) { /* handle input for  athletes[n].feet; athletes[n].inches; */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code:

- The format specifier to be used whenever you are using float is `%f` instead you are using `%d`
- Try forward declaring your `calculateInches()` method. Write it above the `main()` method or try using a function prototype. have a look at this [link](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/a/24338)
- Mention the right types for the arguments to the function `float calculateInches(float feet, int inches)`. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18202232/5281962)

Working example: https://ideone.com/jsMZgv

Comment: Ah ok after comparing the examples I see that as you mentioned I completely forgot to even specify the types for feet and inches. After adding that everything seems to work fine. Thanks for the help!