# Why does a function prototype with an empty argument list conflicts with one that has a char argument?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, standards, c11

With the code below, both clang and gcc called with -std=c11 complain about conflicting types for foo.

```
int foo();

int main(void) {
  return foo(0);
}

int foo(char a) {
   return a;
}
```

According to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950800/1078224, in (older?) C standards the type int has been assumed when no variable type was given. However, the C11 standard draft (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.7.6.3, $14 says that

> The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the
>   parameters is supplied.

From this I conclude that the code above should be actually valid. Or am I missing some other relevant section of the standard?

Comment: The fact that this is confusing is yet another argument for *always* using prototypes.

Comment: Pay attention to the line numbers -- the error is on the line of the function *definition*, not on the line of the function *call*.  http://ideone.com/mi5Eq2

Comment: The implicit `int` rule was dropped in the 1999 standard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.6.3 15:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types. Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types. If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and **the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions**.… [Emphasis added.]

`char` is promoted to `int`, so `char a` is not compatible with an empty list. `int a` would be; `int foo(); int foo(int a);` is allowed.

Essentially, the reason for this is that, if you declare a function `int foo()` and then call it, say with `int foo(3)`, the compiler has to know what to pass it. The rules, derived from history, are to perform the default argument promotions. So `int foo(3)` gets called as if it were `int foo(int)`.

Then, if you later define the function with `int foo(char)`, the definition will not match the call. In many C implementations a `char` and an `int` may be put in the same place for calling a function, but a C implementation could do something different. A `float` and a `double` would be a greater conflict.

Comment: I would also note that there would be a conflicting types issue even without the forward declaration, because the actual call to the function, which happens earlier in the file than the function definition, uses an `int`, which is still different from `char`.

Comment: I don't think `int foo();` and `int foo(int);` are necessarily compatible either; I know of some implementations where a call to a function `int foo();` will always place arguments on the stack, while a call to `int foo(int)` will place its argument in a register.  The only place "default int" is applicable is with the function return type.