# Why have a "warning" when initializing an array of function pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, function-pointers

i try to initializing an array of function pointers and i have "warning":

```
ring-buffer.c:57:19: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
RBufP->rbfunc[0] = &RBufPush;
                 ^
```

but the neighborhood's ok:

```
/*typedef for func pointer*/
typedef RBRetCod_t (*RBFunc)();

/*RBufP*/
typedef struct {
    RBufSiz_t size; /*size and mask*/
    RBufDat_t rbufdat;
    RBufPoint_t head, tail;
    RBFunc rbfunc[3]; /*announce of function pointers array*/
} RBuf_t;
RBuf_t *RBufP;
...

/*init for func pointers array*/
RBufP->rbfunc[2] = &RBufDel; /*it is ok*/
RBufP->rbfunc[1] = &RBufPull; /*it is ok*/
RBufP->rbfunc[0] = &RBufPush; /*it is bad, why???*/

...

/*body of the functions*/
RBRetCod_t RBufPull(unsigned char *dat)
{
        return RBSUCC;
}
RBRetCod_t RBufDel(void)
{
        return RBSUCC;
}
RBRetCod_t RBufPush(unsigned char dat)
{
        return RBSUCC;
}
```

please explain to me why the warning occurs in this line: `RBufP->rbfunc[0] = &RBufPush;`, but in adjacent rows are not there?

Comment: could you show how `RBufP` is defined? and if not presented already, whats the way the type is structured.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Function types without parameters is an old feature in C, but with some strange behaviours. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950642

Comment: @REACHUS gcc with -Wall option

Comment: Do all of your 3 function have a prototype before the code that's using them ?

Comment: @nos Of course, without it does not compiled

Comment: Do you really have to use an array? You could use `struct` instead, and all function pointers could have a correct type.

Answer (score 7):

See C11 section 6.7.6.3 §14, specifying when 2 function types shall be considered compatible:

> [...] If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and **the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions**. [...]

This is the case for `RBufPull` and `RBufDel`, but not `RBufPush` as `unsigned char` gets promoted to `int`.

If you called `RBuPush` through a pointer of type `RBFunc`, an `int` argument would get pushed to the stack, whereas `RBufPush` would expect an `unsigned char`. Depending on calling convention and endianness, you'll get incorrect results.

One solution is to change `RBufPush` to take an `int` argument. Another one is to use a cast, ie

```
RBufP->rbfunc[0] = (RBFunc)&RBufPush;
```

You'll need to cast back to the correct type `RBRetCod_t (*)(unsigned char)` before calling `rbfunc[0]`.

Answer (score 5):

From ISO/IEC:9899:

> J.5.7 Function pointer casts
>
> 1 A pointer to an object or to void may be cast to a pointer to a function, allowing data to
>   be invoked as a function (6.5.4).
>
> 2 A pointer to a function may be cast to a pointer to an object or to void, allowing a
>   function to be inspected or modified (for example, by a debugger) (6.5.4).

But this rule is limited through:

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> [...]
>
> 8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
>   type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. **If a converted
>   pointer is used to call a function** whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, **the behavior is undefined**.

So you are trying to acces different functions with the same Pointerobject type.
This is undefined behavior and the warning therefor is correct.

**Note:**

What it seems to me, what you try to achieve would be something like an interface in `C#`.

But this kind of functionallity is not available in C

Comment: @IvanIvanovich: What exactly are you talking about? Sorry don't get it what you are saying.

Comment: note that it's only UB in case of `RBufPush`, but not `RBufPull` and `RBufDel` due to how empty argument lists work.

Comment: @Christoph: You are right and your answer is anyway better than mine. +1 to yours.