# Function parameters without types in C programming language

Tags: c, function, parameters

Let us consider the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int test(a,b,c)
{
    return a+b+c;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",test(1,2,3));
    printf("%d\n",test(1.5,2.2,2.3));
}
```

I didn't know that it is possible to specify functions in C without defining the types of its parameters. This is a feature of ANSI C? Can someone explain this to me?

I thought it was not possible to do that. However, my compiler can compile this program! In which situations I can do that?

Also, The program behaviour is a little weird. When I use integer values, the function does what we expect. However, when I use float parameters, the result is very different from what I would expect.

Comment: That's not valid C!

Comment: Ok. It's was I thought. However, my compiler (mingW) compiles it withour problems. Why?

Comment: Those 'float' arguments are all of type `double`; you'd have to write `1.5F` to make them of type `float`.  When there's no prototype for a function, as there isn't with `test()`, then all parameters undergo default promotions — integer types shorter than `int` are converted to `int`, and `float` values are converted to `double`.  Using K&R-style function definitions these days is an extremely bad idea, but they are still allowed by the C11 standard.  You should never write one yourself; you should aim to upgrade any you find in the code you work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile this code using `GCC`, it will show a warnings like `type of 'a' defaults to ‘int’`, since `C` implicitly assumes type of arguments as `int`, when not specified.

The feature where you don't have to specify the type of an argument in a function was added in order to provide backwards compatibility with older versions of the language, the `K&R` version of the language. When `GCC` encounters an `"old style"` function, it conforms to the old `K&R C behaviour` which implies no warnings in this situation.

One possible reason why you are getting undefined results maybe because the calling code doesn't know that it needs to cast the arguments to `int` and hence passes `float` instead.  Your function `test` then either reads registers/stack locations that `floats` weren't copied to or receives the `bit` representations of `float` arguments and treats them as an `int`. Either of these `will` result in incorrect values of `a, b, c` being received.

Note that if you explicitly specify the type of arguments like `int test(int a, int b, int c)`, then it would type-cast the `floats`, and then pass them to the function, with output `5`.

Comment: I didn't know that C implicitly assumes type of arguments as int, when not specified!!!

I've been writing codes in C for 10 years and I didnt know that!

Comment: Yeah, it exists. Please see this link also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950642/why-does-a-function-with-no-parameters-compared-to-the-actual-function-definiti and mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue :) @Zaratruta