# how to solve a deprecate declaration of a function when compiling warning?

Tags: c, embedded, compiler-warnings, keil

I have 3 file dependencies, in one of them I have implemented one function that you can see the first of all below. It returns an int type of 32 bits. The second file implements a function that calls the funtion of the first file. This function will be called from main file (third file). 
When I compile (with keil IDE) all the files I have the following warning msg:

```
compiling App_Task_CAN.c...
..\src\Application_Tasks\App_Task_CAN.h(132): warning:  #1295-D: Deprecated      declaration App_Task_CAN_GetError - give arg types
  uint32_t App_Task_CAN_GetError();
```

This is a part of code in a file I have included stm32l4xx_hal_can.c:

```
 uint32_t HAL_CAN_GetError(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan)
 {
      return hcan->ErrorCode;
 }
```

where hcan is in stm32l4xx_hal_can.h a type of:

```
   /**
   * @brief  CAN handle Structure definition
   */
 typedef struct
 {
     CAN_TypeDef                 *Instance;  /*!< Register base address          */

     CAN_InitTypeDef             Init;       /*!< CAN required parameters        */

     CanTxMsgTypeDef*            pTxMsg;     /*!< Pointer to transmit structure  */

     CanRxMsgTypeDef*            pRxMsg;     /*!< Pointer to reception structure */

     __IO HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef   State;      /*!< CAN communication state        */

     HAL_LockTypeDef             Lock;       /*!< CAN locking object             */

     __IO uint32_t               ErrorCode;  /*!< CAN Error code                 */ 

}CAN_HandleTypeDef;
```

Furthermore I have this implementation in other file calling to the first shown function in App_Task_CAN.c :

```
...
CAN_HandleTypeDef HCAN_Struct;//hcan struct type declaration in this file

uint32_t App_Task_CAN_GetError()
{   
    static uint32_t ErrorNumb;

    ErrorNumb=HAL_CAN_GetError(&HCAN_Struct);

    return ErrorNumb; //I want this functions returns an int value.
}
```

Main code in main.c:

```
int main(void)
{
    uint32_t    ErrorType=0;

    while (1)
    {
        ErrorType=App_Task_CAN_GetError(); //it takes the resulting value of calling HAL_CAN_GetError(&HCAN_Struct)
    }
}
```

The warning disappears when I pass an argument. But I don't know why it is asking me for a argument for saving the return value.

Why does it needs an argument since it returns an uint32_t? Is it possible to improve the code in order to get updated ErrorType from main when main calls App_Task_CAN_GetError()?

Note: stm32l4xx_hal_can.c and .h can not been modified since they are system libraries files.

Comment: `uint32_t App_Task_CAN_GetError()` --> `uint32_t App_Task_CAN_GetError(void)`

Comment: [why-does-a-function-with-no-parameters-compared-to-the-actual-function-definiti](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950642/why-does-a-function-with-no-parameters-compared-to-the-actual-function-definiti)

Comment: @LPs warning disappears and it works correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Using [c](/questions/tagged/c), the declaration

```
int foo(void)
```

means a function returning `int` that **takes no parameters**. 
The declaration

```
int f()
```

means a function returning `int` that takes **any number of parameters**.

Thus, if you have a function that takes no parameters in [c](/questions/tagged/c), the former is the correct prototype.

Comment: Also note that the compiler was correct to warn about this feature being deprecated, as per 6.11.6 Function declarators "The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
type declarators) is an obsolescent feature."